# Ruby "ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with Array failed"

Tags: ruby, recursion, mergesort

I'm attempting to implement a Ruby merge sort algorithm, and it seems to me from staring at it for awhile that the program *should* work.  However, I'm getting the error listed in the title and I'm not quite sure why. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Full code:

```
def merge_sort(arr)
    return arr if arr.length == 1
    mid = arr.length/2
    left = merge_sort(arr[0..mid-1])
    right = merge_sort(arr[mid..-1])
    merge(left,right)
end

def merge(arr1,arr2,merged=[])

    i=0 #arr1 initialize
    j=0 #arr2 initialize
    while i < arr1.length || j < arr2.length
        if i < arr1.length && j<arr2.length
            if arr1[i] <= arr2[j]
                merged << arr1[i]
                i+=1
            else
                merged << arr2[j]
                j+=1
            end
        elsif i<arr1.length
            merged << arr1[i..-1]
            i=arr1.length
        elsif j<arr2.length
            merged << arr2[j..-1]
            j=arr2.length
        end
    end
    merged
end


array = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
p merge_sort(array)
```

**Error**:

```
$ ruby mergeSort.rb 
mergeSort.rb:15:in `<=': comparison of Fixnum with Array failed (ArgumentError)
    from mergeSort.rb:15:in `merge'
    from mergeSort.rb:6:in `merge_sort'
    from mergeSort.rb:5:in `merge_sort'
    from mergeSort.rb:4:in `merge_sort'
    from mergeSort.rb:36:in `<main>'
```

**Note: here is line 15**

if arr1[i] <= arr2[j]

Comment: It's worth pointing out for the future, given an error in line X, you should start with printing variables on line X-1. For instance, adding `p arr1` and `p arr2` right before line 15. That would have shown you `[8]` and `[6, [7]]` right before the error, which would have then made far more sense. **Never** underestimate the power of printing your variables during debug. :-)

Comment: tt, I laughed when I read, "...it seems to me from staring at it for awhile that the program should work".  I'm sure everyone here is familiar with that technique.

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn that's a great suggestion.  I'll definitely be incorporating that from now on. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are pushing arrays into arrays by calling `<<` in

```
elsif i<arr1.length
  merged << arr1[i..-1]
  i=arr1.length
elsif j<arr2.length
  merged << arr2[j..-1]
  j=arr2.length
end
```

and that creates unwanted nested arrays. When you compare array elements by `arr1[i] <= arr2[j]`, the elements of `arr1` and `arr2` are not necessarily at the same nested level (i.e., they may be an array or not an array). That causes the error.

If you change the `<<` in the part above to `concat`, then it will work.

Comment: Perfect solution. I hadn't considered that at all... strange that it reported the error on line 15 rather than down below where the error actually was. Thanks!

Comment: No, the error is indeed raised on line 15. There is nothing wrong with creating a nested array (although that is not what you intended). What is wrong is that you tried to compare such arrays.